# What are the disadvantages of dichotomizing an ordinal DV?

Tags: ordinal-data

I have an ordinal dependent variable in my model. Personally I find dealing with binary variable a lot more simple, although I have been told that by dichotomizing my DV I will lose information. What exactly would be lost?

Comment: Your job, perhaps. When I used to work for a manufacturing company, the Quality Engineers were putting great effort & ingenuity into devising ordinal measurement scales to replace crude pass/fail assessments. I don't think I'd've been there very long if I'd dichotomized them because I found binary variables simpler to deal with.

Comment: Not just lose information, but you'll bias your estimates -- the estimated mean of all the categories will be shifted toward the mean of the categories you lumped it in with. Your standard errors will be affected. All manner of things happen. Whether this is only mildly bad or terrible depends on a number of things, including what you're trying to achieve, but generally it's to be avoided.

Answer (score 7):

Everything.  The meaning of the variable is lost, information is lost, and statistical power is diminished.  Why even consider this?

Why is it so difficult to deal with ordinal regression models?  If using a proportional odds model and you want to interpret effects in terms of odds ratios, you still get an odds ratio for each predictor.  Instead of being the ratio of odds that $Y=1$ it's the ratio of odds for $Y\geq j$ for arbitrary $j$.

You can also use ordinal models to estimate exceedance probabilities and mean $Y$ (plus quantiles of $Y$ if $Y$ is continuous).